# My web developer is struggling to integrate SagePay into my Wordpress website

Tags: opayo

I have 3 questions as of now, please consider and reply point wise, thank you..

1. I understand the use of Encryption Password (56071ba432970392) and i'm using it to construct the "crypt" field.
   But please let me know if the "Encryption key" and "Integration Password" are necessary in the "Form method", as i do not see it's reference in the Form integration protocol guide (https://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/25041/download-document/FORM_Integration_and_Protocol_Guidelines_270815.pdf?token=xecgCPxo3AAFu8UiqobWCsfHOZwMz44crX7lYbBHdvM)

### 2. In the above guide, in page no. 10 / annex. 3.0 / Step 2 > There are 4 hidden fields to be sent to sagepay in  url and below is the exact data which is sent but with 5080 error code.

```
include("lib/sagepay.php");
$key = '56071ba432970392';

$paymentString = "VendorTxCode=abc123&Amount=$amount&Currency=GBP&Description=$description&BillingSurname=$lname&BillingFirstnames=$fname&BillingAddress1=$address&BillingCity=$city&BillingPostCode=$zip&BillingCountry=$country&DeliverySurname=$lname&DeliveryFirstnames=$fname&DeliveryAddress1=$address&DeliveryCity=$city&DeliveryPinCode=$zip&DeliveryCountry=$country&SuccessURL=https://www.life-changing-adventures.com/success&FailureURL=https://www.life-changing-adventures.com/failure";

<input type="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value="3.00">
<input type="hidden" name="TxType" value="PAYMENT">
<input type="hidden" name="Vendor" value="lifechangingadv">
<input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value='<?php echo SagepayUtil::encryptAes($paymentString, $key); ?>'>
------------------------------
```

3. In the sagepay online support page (https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/error-codes/5080-error-form-transaction-registration-failed)
   for 5080 error, it says "You will need to log into your Sage pay account. Once you have logged in select the transactions tab, and then the Invaild sub screen from the options on the left."

But as attached, the "invalid" tab screen is empty from the start, so i cannot figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

1. The encryption key is accessed via your MySagePay admin user (uses the same username as your vendorname).
2. 5080 error - https://www.opayo.co.uk/support/error-codes?keyword=5080
3. If your encryption is not being done as expected you will receive this error.  If you are encrypting correctly you will reach the Opayo payment process.  The invalid tab only populates when you have done this and have then passed an invalid character in a field for example.